# Create a private pod , source attribute without any repository

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have created a private pod, but when I run `pod install` , I c the following error.

I know I am missing "source" , but for private pod which I don't want to upload to any git. repository. What could be a solution for it.

pod install

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `MyLib` from `../MyLib`
[!] The `MyLib` pod failed to validate due to 1 error:
    - ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute `source`.
    - WARN  | homepage: The homepage has not been updated from default
    - WARN  | summary: The summary is not meaningful.
```

.podspec is as below

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|


  s.name         = "MyLib"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of MyLib."


  s.description  = "This is a my Lib. It can be used for post and get request"

  s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/MyLib"

  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = { "Abc Bbc" => "abcd@abcd.com" }
  s.source_files  = 'MyLib', 'MyLib/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.public_header_files = 'MyLib/**/*.h'
  s.resources    = "MyLib/*.png"
  s.framework    = 'SystemConfiguration'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a :path-based source like s.source = { :path => '.' }. If you're using :path in your Podfile, it will be overridden anyway, so the value does not really matter in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods is git based, so to use a private repository your pod must be available as a publicly readable git repo and the source set to that repo in your Podfile.

As an alternative to Cocoapods that might fit your use case better (by letting you keep your repo private) I would suggest checking out https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules. Submodules allow you to include another git project directly within your project and repo but under separate version control, making it easy to pull down changes to site submodule.

Comment: Referring to a blog at http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/developing-static-library-for-ios-with-cocoapods/ . This one shows it can work without source attribute.

Comment: The blog post is from 2014, so it is possible that things have changed since then.